# Trying to create sequential on.click events

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I created an initial on click event that produces part of a picture. Once that has run, I am trying to create another on click event that will continue producing a part of the picture. Once the initial on click event runs, the second one I have created does not. Do I need an additional "if" statement? Here's what I have so far and there are three frames in each on click event:

```
$(function() {
    var frames = $('#animation').children();
    var frameCount = frames.length;

    function startAnimation() { 
        var i = 0;
        var animationInterval = setInterval(function () { 
        if(i > frameCount - 1) {
            clearInterval(animationInterval);
        } else {
            frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
            frames[i++].style.display = "inline";
        }
        },1000); 
    }

    $(frames[0]).on('click', startAnimation);


    var frames1 = $('#animation1').children();
    var frameCount1 = frames1.length;


    function continueAnimation() { 
        var i = 0;
        var animationInterval1 = setInterval(function () { 
        if(i < frameCount - 1) {
            clearInterval(animationInterval1);
        } else {
            frames1[i % frameCount1].style.display = "block";
            frames1[i++].style.display = "inline";
        }  
        },1000); 
    }

    $(frames[3]).on('click', continueAnimation);
});
```

Comment: a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) example would be great

Comment: Hey Ergec, no problem, here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/jeminip/gEF7G/1/ . For some reason I can't get the images to show up. Also, sorry for re-posting this comment like 10 billion times

Comment: I have no idea what you are after but let's give it a go. Check this one out http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/56qfK/6/

Comment: Perfect, this worked! I'm basically trying to show the progress of a seed growing into a tree through images. The plant grows as different parts of it are clicked. Do you mind explaining the console log part added in? Thanks so much!

Comment: I posted my answer if you kindly accept it. I added logs to understand what's going on, you may remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix I did, check it out

```
...
```

[jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/ergec/56qfK/6)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JQuery's delegate functionality (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). It's a little difficult to provide you with any code at this point--as Ergec commented, a JS Fiddle example would be great. Your problem basically stems from how .on() works, it only registers that trigger when the DOM is loaded and not for subsequent changes to the DOM, this is where .delegate('event', 'target', function(event) {}); comes in handy as it allows you to attach events programmatically even for subsequent DOM changes.

Comment: Actually `.on()` does work for subsequent changes to the DOM. `$("body").on("click", ".selector", function () { do stuff here })` is equivalent to `$(".selector").live("click", function () { do stuff here });`

Comment: Thanks for that Ergec, after checking out the JQuery website it looks like delegate was the preferred method for v 1.4 - 1.7, but as of 1.7+ on() is the preferred method. Thanks for alerting me to that--always good to learn something new!